# exchange 2010 - diagnostic logging

Tags: exchange

One of my users is having random issues sending email. The email will look like it gets sent and even gets stamped with "you replied to this message". However, later on the user notices the email has the word "draft" in it as it was never sent.

When I look at message-tracking I see the eventid for these emails as "submitFail". When I expand on the command it says "EventWithoutSubmitFlag". The source is STOREDRIVER. I've tried to turn on diagnostic logging on the servers to expert to see if I can get additional info on why this is happening but it's not getting much extra logging. Below are the ones I've turned expert on for. What else can I log expert for?

MSExchange Store Driver\General ||| Expert

MSExchange TransportService\TransportService ||| Expert

MSExchangeMailSubmission\General ||| Expert

Comment: I asked a similar question regarding submit fail but no one has replied. I changed this question around and made it about logging. Also I've already wipe the user's outlook profile to see if it was a client issue.

Comment: Check if the mailbox has proper full access rights for `NT AUTHORITY\SELF` and actual user in case of a linked mailbox. Also if mailbox is linked check if `linkedMasterAccount` property in the mailbox is correct. Also, how often does this issue arise? Is it 100% or not?

Comment: SELF is part of their mailbox permission. No linked mailbox. It's their own mailbox. It's a random issue so it could be a few days before it happens again. Also when I first started looking into this I noticed the submitFail eventID in message tracking and that's why I've linked that event with the issue but I could be wrong.

Comment: The event matched the timestamp of the issue but I've seen more eventIDs for this issue and they haven't complained. They might not have noticed or like I said it might not be related? What's more worrisome is that now I'm seeing other users with some submitFail eventIDs. It used to just be one person. It's not a bunch of users everyday but it'll be one random user every few days.

Comment: Weird situation really. I'd ask Microsoft support on such an issue if it won't get fixed in a week or so. Haven't met anything like that yet. There might be some problems with DAG configuration, replication latency or something like that, this might in turn cause HARECEIVE events to not generate thus preventing servers to employ high availability so they freak out on that and say "we'd better not receive the message at all", for example. Don't get what else you can check yet, sorry.

Comment: I can definitely try turning up logging for DAG. I'm not sure if this issue has been happening all along or just recently. In the two years I've been here no one ever reported this issue so I never looked for submitFail events before. The closest thing I found online was of exchange producing this event when email was in fact sent correctly and it might have been a bug. So the ones I'm seeing now could have been sent fine and no users are complaining. But my exchange is patched up to patch before the latest CU. Thanks for your suggestion on possible DAG issue.